# WP7 ProgressBar Height and Colour Troubles

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'd like to change the height of the progress bar within my project however the height property doesn't seem to be doing anything when I set it. Also, is it possible to change the colour of the progress bar from the default blue to another colour? Orange for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ProgressBar have two colours. A background, which is the background of the ProgressBar at all times, and the foreground which is the colour of the ProgressBar when it have a Value that's greater than the minimum. Both can be customized easily, but keep in mind that it defaults to using the Accent colour of the phone, which is recommended, unless you have a *really* good reason.

To change the actual height, override it's ControlTemplate, and change the height of the `ProgressBarIndicator` and the `ProgressBarTrack`, like this: (here set to 20px)

```
<Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <!-- Visual States removed for clarity -->
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="DeterminateRoot" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Visible">


                        <!-- CHANGE THE HEIGHT HERE -->
                        <Rectangle x:Name="ProgressBarTrack" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="20" Opacity="0.1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="ProgressBarIndicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20"/>


                    </Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="IndeterminateRoot" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <Grid>
                            <Slider x:Name="Slider1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                            <Slider x:Name="Slider2" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                            <Slider x:Name="Slider3" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                            <Slider x:Name="Slider4" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                            <Slider x:Name="Slider5" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Beneath my progress bar, I tried typing up your solution however "TargetType" does not appear to be a valid option for style? If I ignore it and type it up anyway, I see "The property content is set more than once".

Comment: If you use it as a inline style, you shouldn't use a `TargetType`. Instead you need to wrap it in <ProgressBar.Style> around it. (This is very basic XAML stuff.). However, the way I wrote it, you should place it in a ResourceDictionary, for example in `<App.Resources>` in `App.xaml`

Comment: Great, thanks :) All working now. Do you know where I can see the original control template for the progress bar?

Comment: I posted it ;-) And I use Expression Blend for this. But you can find the Styles in some XAML files, see this article: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Mango-Custom-application-Theme-Step-by-Step

Comment: You are an absolute champion. Thank you so much.